# Why do regexreplace and regexextract in Google Sheets work differently?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

In this string

> ID="APPLE"; TEXT="APPLE"; FOO="BAR";

I'll use this regex

> TEXT="(.*?)"

To change TEXT="APPLE"'s APPLE to BANANA.

Using regexextract return

> APPLE

but then regexreplace returns

> ID="APPLE"; BANANA; FOO="BAR";

which I think it should be TEXT="BANANA", considering APPLE is what regexextract returned.

What should I do to make it like this?

> ID="APPLE"; TEXT="BANANA"; FOO="BAR";

[Example link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTURwuYBda7V-Z9pBHbpjQxL-yqI3BoDQMiBBmxMrDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me.  In a sample sheet, please provide some data, the formulas you've tried, and what you expect the outcome to look like.

Comment: Updated the sheet. regexextract using TEXT="(.*?)" returns APPLE so I assumed using the same expression for regexreplace with 3rd argument as BANANA would replace APPLE with BANANA, but it replaces the whole block instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck for this issue.

First of all [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) has stated in the documentation that it actually will change all the matched text:

> `regular_expression` - The regular expression. All matching instances in text will be replaced.

So even if using capturing groups you will get the whole matched string. I don't know if this could be an issue or intended behavior, you can still report if you feel like so (**Help>Send feedback to Google**).

Another way of thinking is using look ahead and look behind to avoid matching unwanted text.

```
(?<=TEXT=")(.*?)(?=";)
```

The problem with this approach is that google's sheet functions use the [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/) implementation for regular expression. Meaning that look ahead and look behind [are not implemented](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

---

#### Workaround

My suggestion to overcome all the issues would be to create a simple Apps Script custom function so you can use the regular expression of javascript.

I did a very straightforward code for your case

```
function sensibleRegExpReplace(input, regEx, replace){

  var reg = new RegExp(regEx);

  return input.replace(reg, replace);

}
```

And you would get the following result:

[image: Example of result]

I guess that there could be a way of doing all of this using only built in sheets functions using helper cells. But I haven't managed to make it work and this feel more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This expression matches the whole string and also identifies a regular expression group, i.e. what is within ()

TEXT="(.*?)"

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/U-zf7FdnZr3y1GBv)

With **Regexmatch** you can check that there is a correct match in the whole expression, that is why Regexreplace replaces everything.

Regextract captures the group defined within the regular expression .

The expression to obtain the expected is: `=REGEXREPLACE(B6,B8, "TEXT=$1")` where $1 is the group defined in the regular expression.